Windows 11 Recycle Bin often takes a while to empty
What happens is that when it has something like more than 20 files in it, or if any of the files are larger—say, in the order of giga-bytes—then the "emptying bin" dialogue-box will get to "99% completed" but then stay like for a minute or so. Then, hovering over File Explorer will make the message appear in its window-bar that says "File Explorer is not responding". However, it always seems to resolve itself eventually and I don't think I've had it yet fail to empty altogether. Is this normal behaviour please? Also, after emptying the message "Working on it..." will always be displayed inside the Recycling Bin until I either close that instance of File Explorer or else click to a different folder; and then that "Working on it..." message will have gone the next time I click on the Recycling Bin.
The max size set for the Drive I'm using is 26GB, and I never fill it anything close to that figure.
Below are the results of a chkdsk operation I did to investigate the matter. I regularly do sfc /scannow and DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth checks which hardly ever find any problems with the system.
The hardware is all pretty new, I really doubt the hardware has anything to do with it.
=================================================
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Wininit
Date:          11/07/2024 14:47:14
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      imperfect
Description:
Checking file system on C:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
A disk check has been scheduled.
Windows will now check the disk.
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
503808 file records processed.
File verification completed.
Phase duration (File record verification): 3.43 seconds.
19738 large file records processed.
Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 8.15 milliseconds.
0 bad file records processed.
Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 1.69 milliseconds.
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
5235 reparse records processed.
848336 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
Phase duration (Index verification): 9.61 seconds.
0 unindexed files scanned.
Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 510.09 milliseconds.
0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 914.61 milliseconds.
5235 reparse records processed.
Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 18.43 milliseconds.
Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Cleaning up 1460 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 1460 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 1460 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 26.34 milliseconds.
172265 data files processed.
Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 1.86 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
36472112 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
Phase duration (USN journal verification): 58.14 milliseconds.
Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
503792 files processed.
File data verification completed.
Phase duration (User file recovery): 2.93 minutes.
Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
71373420 free clusters processed.
Free space verification is complete.
Phase duration (Free space recovery): 43.20 seconds.
Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.
499191807 KB total disk space.
212619732 KB in 265936 files.
450544 KB in 172266 indexes. 

     0 KB in bad sectors. 

627851 KB in use by the system. 

 65536 KB occupied by the log file. 

285493680 KB available on disk.
  4096 bytes in each allocation unit. 

124797951 total allocation units on disk.
71373420 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 3.90 minutes (234136 ms).
Internal Info:
00 b0 07 00 6f af 06 00 43 59 0c 00 00 00 00 00  ....o...CY......
a5 13 00 00 ce 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

This is pretty normal.
Aside of your drive having a cache, when actually deleting files on an SSD, it will also use TRIM. Although you did not specify that you are using an SSD, it would explain the wait at the end at 99%.
The function TRIM will go through all cells that had content but are deleted to mark them as completely empty. A sort of defragging. As long as there is enough free space on the SSD, TRIM will ensure that the drive remains fast.
The reason I mention cache, is because when you perform a function, it will try to use cache mostly, which means that even though the operation is not done yet, it is performed out of cache, and then windows will already report the operation to be finished, while it still is doing some operations.
It is also possible that the cache runs out, so when there is more data to be changed than the size of the cache, once the cache runs out, the speed will lower. This is especially noticable with a copy of mutiple large files, where the speed seems fast and suddenly it becomes slower but steady.

Great. Yes my laptop uses an SSD, so it sounds like what you say there is what's happening with it and so there's nothing to worry about. Thanks.

If you have one larger file (or collection) that you want to delete, delete it with shift-delete to permanently delete it instead of moving it to the recyclebin, and you'll see the exact same thing happening.

As in it will still take a while to delete, I see. Cheers.
